# PowerShell Remoting: On execution of a command to start an exe (wmplayer for example), can't see the actual UI

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have a test bed in my lab consisting of a windows server 2008 running powershell 2.0. I am using that server to manage 50 clients  that are connected wired and wireless with the server. I am running windows Active Directory on the server and all the clients are in the domain I created and I am using the AD to push different policies. I have a lot of basic scripts running (shutting down all interfaces on the clients, shutting down clients, fetching logs from clients etc.). But there is one Task in particular that is extremely important for my setup and I am facing a lot of issues with it. Here are the details:

---

I want to start some applications like windows media player or a VLC player on all the clients through a script. The script will be run on the server and it should try and establish connection with all the clients and bring up the UI.

What has been tried?

Method 1:
**New-Pssession -computername  -credential 
Enter Pssession -id**

(brings up the prompt on the remote machine)
**start-process wmplayer.exe**

Everything runs correctly. A process gets created on the client, but I do not see the UI.

Method 2:
I created a batch file on the remote machine that runs the wmplayer.exe. It works fine and brings up the UI if executed manually from the client, but again if triggered remotely it only creates a process and does not bring up the UI.

Am I missing something while running the commands? Do I need to configure something more to get the UI up and running?

Comment: AFAIK, Windows prevents you from doing this for security reasons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running remote GUI app in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570517/running-remote-gui-app-in-powershell)

Comment: Thanks a lot [Bill](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart) and [Mike](http://stackoverflow.com/users/517852/mike-z)

I read somewhere that if we use PsExec on a group of clients, it executes commands on one machine at a time instead of doing parallel execution. Is that true?