# How do I run an executable stored on a networked machine on that same machine?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm producing an application that needs to launch multiple programs on networked PCs, and I need to run the programs on the PCs on which they reside, not the local PC. For example, if I have 5 PCs on the network, I'll store the paths to each PC's program (and arguments) within an array containing 5 elements; the application will need to run the program stored on PC1 on PC1, the program stored on PC2 on PC2, and so on.

One important thing to note is that the programs, written in Unity, have a full-blown UI that needs to be displayed on their corresponding PC.

Please could somebody give me hints as to how to accomplish this. I ideally don't want to use any hacks or third-party software. If it helps, each of the PCs will be logged into before the programs run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PsExec from SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570517/running-remote-gui-app-in-powershell)

`& ".\psexec" -accepteula -i "\\computername" -u "domain\username" -p "password" "command line"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is there any purely-code solution that can do the same thing? I've read that WMI might be an option, but I've no idea how I'd get it to work?