# Starting WPF from remote PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell

I want to open a WPF application from remote machine using PowerShell. 
This is the command I'm using

```
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName "ComputerNamne" -ScriptBlock { & "C:\...App.exe" } -credential "Username"
```

but for some reason nothing happens

I was able to start the process when calling batch file which calls the applcation

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "ComputerNamne" -ScriptBlock { & "C:\...RubApp.bat" } -credential "Username"
```

but in this way the GUI is not appearing. I can see in task manager that the app is running though.

So two questions:

1. Why can't I run directly the exe file?
2. Why the GUI is hidden in the second method. Can I solve this?

Comment: Here's different ways to start program in powershell: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx . I would use  Start-Process  (start/saps)

Comment: You can't run a graphical app from `invoke-command` or other WinRM methods. If you want to do that, look into using `psexec` with the `-i` switch

Comment: @maximdumont, you can run graphical apps using this method?

Comment: Thanks @BenH.
I'll look into it

Comment: Start-Process doesn't run on remote computers. Wrapping it in `invoke-command` will run you into the same issues. The ways you can make it "work" with a `invoke-command` would be scheduling a task or creating start-up script

Comment: @BenH, Are you sure the I can run GUI application using psexec ? 
I'm getting the same behavior. Task is created in task manager but not UI?
Command: PsExec \\machine -i -d "C:\..App.exe"

Comment: Try adding the console id after `-i`. If you are trying to display in console session 2, you would use: `PsExec \\machine -i 2 -d "C:\..App.exe"`

Comment: @BenH, Adding console id did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

For invoking GUI app , you have to use **PSexec** with **-i** :

You can download it from here and you will get to know how to use also.
[PSTools Download](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Ranadip on this one. This is not a feature of powershell, as neither WinRM nor WMI will allow you to utilize a GUI application remotely.

See a similar question:
[Running remote GUI app in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570517/running-remote-gui-app-in-powershell)