# OpenGL and Remote Desktop

Tags: opengl, remote-desktop

I have trouble using OpenGL over Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) on a Windows 10 computer.
The server has an NVIDIA GEFORCE 8600 GT. 
Yet, OpenGL reports the card is a GDI Generic Device.
The driver is up to date v342.01

I know for sure OpenGL over RDC is possible for I am able to do so with another server equipped with a Quadro.

Do I need to enable an option in Windows for it to work? Or is it jus not possible with this graphic card?

Comment: What is your client machine?

Comment: My client machine is a Windows 10 desktop, core i7, NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 970

Comment: I also need to mention that if I start the application locally, I can use  OpenGL remotelly without any problem.

Comment: Your last comment is confusing (mainly because it's not clear what locally means). You have a client and a server. Do you mean: "when I start the application on the server, then connect remotely from the client, then I can use OpenGL"? Meaning that "If I connect from client to server and app is not started, then I start the app, then app fails to start"?

Comment: @cdavid you are correct

Comment: Seems on a server that has a Quadro graphic card there is no such issue.

Comment: @Milo: Nvidia limits OpenGL over RDP to their professional grade GPUs, that's why it doesn't work with "consumer" GeForces.

Comment: They do indeed state Quadro cards support remote desktop at http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/76507/en-us
I found no such statement on GeForce driver release notes.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct answer. Quadro is the only card that is allowed to do OpenGL over RDP.

Comment: Everyone here, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61582432/717732). On Windows 10, it's probably a matter of enabling GPU use over RPD via Group Policy.

Answer (score 2):

Is MS Remote Desktop necessary in your case?

1. If it is - you can try to use scheduler to start OpenGL app. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37536333/1688267) is a simple powershell script to do this remotely (it assumes you [enabled powershell remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)).
2. If not - try some other remote access software ([VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com) or something similar)

Answer (score 2):

Dude i know there is a solution, but for now i only know that works with admin users, and you jhay to instal de pstools, here es the code, of the bat, also create a shortcut for the bat and run it as an admin.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F %%A in ('qwinsta') do (
    set tempSessionName=%%A
    if "!tempSessionName:~0,1!"==">"  (
        psexec -s tscon.exe !tempSessionName:~1! /dest:console
    )   
)
```

this code will take you out of your session, you will need to add a line to open your software at the end, you need to recconect again and will open the software that you need included the opengl