# Change GDI Generic to OpenGL to render over Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows, opengl, glfw, remote-desktop

When I use `glfwCreateWindow` to create window, it returns `NULL`. So I use `OpenGL Extensions Views` to check the version of opengl, it shows 1.1. My GPU is `GeForce RTX 2080 Ti` and the graphics driver is 441.22. The system is win10. I want to update the opengl version, but `OpenGL Extensions Views` shows the system only supports 1.2 and the renderer is 'GDI Generic'. I change the  `OpenGL rendering GPU` to `GeForce RTX 2080 Ti` of global settings in Nvidia control panel, it's still useless. I used the remote desktop of window, all descriptions happen on the remote.
I don’t know if there’s any relationship between using a graphics card and remote desktop. So how can I change the renderer to `GeForce RTX 2080 Ti` and update opengl version?

Comment: "I don’t know if there’s any relationship between using a graphics card and remote desktop."  Oh, [there very much is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705471).

Comment: Remote desktop can only use  `GDI Generic`,  can't use `GeForce RTX 2080 Ti `? But shouldn't the software and environment be remote?